# How may numpy return a length one object array?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy 1.8.2, when I index a numpy array of fixed length strings and ask for one value, I get back a numpy array of length 1, supporting numpy operations. So:

```
import numpy as np
strs = np.array(('aa', 'bbb', 'c'), dtype=np.dtype('|S4'))
print type(strs[(0,)])
```

I get

```
<type 'numpy.string_'>
```

If I do the same with an array of objects:

```
strs = np.array(('aa', 'bbb', 'c'), dtype=np.dtype('object'))
print type(strs[(0,)])
```

I get

```
<type 'str'>
```

and any numpy specific property/method (e.g. .shape) returns an exception

How may I ensure that numpy returns me a length one array of objects from slicing?

Answer (score 0):

From the Data type objects Documentation:

"An item extracted from an array, e.g., by indexing, will be a Python object whose type is the scalar type associated with the data type of the array.

Note that the scalar types are not dtype objects, even though they can be used in place of one whenever a data type specification is needed in Numpy."

By using the `dtype=np.dtype('object')`, you are therefore creating a numpy array that is only filled with scalar types. A numpy array is defined as:
"homogeneous, and contains elements described by a dtype object. A dtype object can be constructed from different combinations of fundamental numeric types."

[Numpy Array Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `strs[(0,)]` is returning a 0d array, shape `()`.

Using a list index, gives a 1d array

```
In [170]: strs[[0]]
Out[170]: 
array([b'aa'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

A true slice returns that same: `strs[0:1]`, `strs[:1]`.

These methods also work with the `object` array

```
In [175]: strs1[:1]
Out[175]: array(['aa'], dtype=object)
```

`strs[(0,)]` is the same as `strs[0]`.  In fact, the later is short for the former.  It selects an item from the array, reducing the dimensionality by 1 (e.g. from 1d to 0d).

`dtype=object` is an odd ball case, stretching the normal `numpy` behavior.  So it's not surprising that it behaves a little different in this case.  Whether it should or not is something you could ask on the `github` developers' site.